# In pytorch, how can I sum some elements, and get a tensor of smaller shape?

Tags: sum, pytorch, tensor

Specifically I have a tensor of dimension 298x160x160 (faces in 298 frames), I need to sum every 4x4 element in last two dimesnion so that I can get a 298x40x40 tensor.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Convolutional layer with a single 4x4 channel and set its weights to 1, with a stride of 4 ([also see Conv2D doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=conv#torch.nn.Conv2d)):

```py
a = torch.ones((298,160,160))
# add a dimension for the channels. Conv2D expects the input to be : (N,C,H,W)
# where N=number of samples, C=number of channels, H=height, W=width
a = a.unsqueeze(1)
a.shape
```

> `Out: torch.Size([298, 1, 160, 160])`

```py
with torch.no_grad(): # I assume you don't need to backprop, otherwise remove this check
    m = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=4,stride=4,bias=False)
    # set the kernel values to 1
    m.weight.data = m.weight.data * 0. + 1.
# apply the kernel and squeeze the channel dim out again
res = m(a).squeeze()
res.shape
```

> `Out: torch.Size([298, 40, 40])`